# Laravel - Get the View name based on full path of the file

Tags: laravel, view

I wonder if I can get the `View name` based on `full path of the view file`.

Code example (expectation code):

```
$full_path = "D:\laragon\www\my-laravel-app\resources\views\user\login.blade.php";
$view_name = get_view_name($full_path);

echo $view_name; 

// My expectation result should be $view_name = "user.login";
// 
// So, it should echo this ---> user.login
```

Can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got a solution.

```
function get_view_name($full_path){
    $view_root_path = config('view.paths')[0];

    $view_name = strtr($full_path, [
        $view_root_path.'/' => '',
        '.blade.php' => '',
        '/' => '.',
    ]);

    return $view_name;
}
```

But I think this is quite dirty solution.

So, I still hope if someone else got better and clean solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can get name of route by using this

```
$request->route()->getName();
```

Or if you don't have $request where you want name of route you can achieve this with **Request** class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request

Request::route()->getName();
```

Comment: I'm sorry brother....My question is "get view name", and not "get route name"... By the way, thanks for try to help...